# I want to run and display names of cities of a particular region in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
southeast(awka,is_in_south-east_Nigeria).
southeast(orlu,is_in_south-east_Nigeria).
southeast(owerri,is_in_south-east_Nigeria).
southeast(aba,is_in_south-east_Nigeria).

city(awka,southeast).
city(orlu,southeast).
city(owerri,southeast).
city(aba,southeast).

city(C,Z):-southeast(C,Z).
```

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is a language based on a *relational* data model.

As such, it need the same kind of care required when designing a RDBMS.
Maybe you should introduce some additional relation, like, for instance

```
% state(ID, Name)
state(1, 'Nigeria').

% region(ID, StateID, Name)
region(1, 1, 'south east').

% city(ID, Name, RegionId)
city(1, awka, 1).
city(2, orlu, 1).
% etc...
```

and provide queries over the DB:

```
city_in_region(City, Location) :-
   city(_, City, RegionId),
   region(RegionId, StateId, Region),
   state(StateId, State),
   format(atom(Location), '~s is in ~s of ~s', [City, Region, State]).
```

and you get

```
?- city_in_region(C,R).
C = awka,
R = 'awka is in south east of Nigeria' ;
C = orlu,
R = 'orlu is in south east of Nigeria'.
```